# How to check performClick() is starting a new Fragment class in Android JUnit

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-fragments

Android JUnit test framework provides ActivityMonitor to test the start of an activity. In the same is there any procedure to test the start of a fragment class instead of activity.
The following is my code and i have to write a JUnit testcase for this code.

My code:
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SecondFragment frag= new SecondFragment ();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            FragmentManager fragmentmanager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmenttransation = fragmentmanager
                    .beginTransaction();
            fragmenttransation.replace(R.id.viewers, frag);
            fragmenttransation.commit();
        }

    });
```

Please suggest a way to test this code using JUnit Android

Comment: You may try robolectric http://robolectric.org/writing-a-test/